# JavaScript searching for a string in a string with an exact separator

Tags: javascript, arrays, search

I have the following string in a JS variable:

1sPos1234sArticle33342sQuantity2sPos4321sArtikcle24333sQuantity

As you can see, I have a separator for each Position called sPos, for each Article called sArticle and for each Quantity called sQuantity.

Now I want to search for all Positions (in this string case: 1,2 and 3) via my separator sPos. Id like to get the string before the sPos seperator.

The same thing I want to do with sArticle and sQuantity.

---

Hopefully someone can help me out.

Cheers!

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: `'1sPos1234sArticle33342sQuantity2sPos4321sArtikcle24333sQuantity'.split('sPos')` ?

Comment: I have just the variable with the string like cited above. I just need a solution to search for the values with the separator (sPos, sArticle, sQuantity) as restriction.

Comment: Split will not do it. If I would do so. Im getting the following string: 1,1234sArticle3342sQuantity and so on. I want JUST the values before the sPos seperator.

Comment: Hi Herz, I cant get your question clearly. Upto my understanding do you want the array of strings coming in the result to be concatenated .?

Comment: //Call C# WebService
  //ret Value contains the string like 1sPos1234sArticle43223sQuantity
  var retValue = P2Service.get("server").checkAngebotPosAufMenge(ANGEBOT.value);
  
  //Want to get all "position values" before the sPos seperator
  var positionen = new Array();
  alert(retValue.split('sPos'));

  This code doesn´t work as I want =|

Answer (score 0):

Well just split it?!?

var myString = 1sPos1234sArticle33342sQuantity2sPos4321sArtikcle24333sQuantity;

var posArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < myString.split("sPos").lenght(); i++) {

var curPos = myString.split("sPos")[i];
curPos = curPos.split("sQuantity")[1];

posArray.push(curPos);

}

var quantityArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < myString.split("sQuantity").lenght(); i++) {

var curQuantity = myString.split("sQuantity")[i];
curQuantity = curQuantity.split("sPos")[1];

posArray.push(curQuantity);

}

This code should solve your problem, but you should not do it the way you doing it... Use JSON unsträflich